# Given that the equations in $x$ :- $3[x - 2(x + \frac{a}{3})] = 2x$ and $\frac{3x + a}{3} - \frac{1 + 4x}{6} = 0$ has a common solution , find it .

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, problem-solving

> Given that the equations in $x$ :- $3[x - 2(x + \frac{a}{3})] = 2x$ and $\frac{3x + a}{3} - \frac{1 + 4x}{6} = 0$ has a common solution , find it .

**What I Tried** :- We have :-

$\frac{3x + a}{3} - \frac{1 + 4x}{6} = 0$

=> $\frac{6x + 2a - 1 - 4x}{6} = 0$

=> $2x + 2a - 1 = 0$

=> $x = \frac{1 - 2a}{2}$ .

Substitute $x$ in the $1$st equation to get :-

$3[x - 2(x + \frac{a}{3})] = 1 - 2a$

=> $3[-x - \frac{2a}{3}] = 1 - 2a$

=> $-3x - 2a = 1 - 2a$

=> $x = -\frac{1}{3}.$

I got the value of $x$ , and I suppose I will find $a$ too , but how to find the common solution?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: This value of $x$ for the corresponding value of $a$ is your common solution. You can verify by substituting back in both the equations.

Comment: $x=-\frac 1 3$ is not correct. You forgot the parentheis in $(x-2)$.

Comment: Wait , what mistake did I do, there is no parenthesis there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already computed $x=-\frac 13$ and $x=\frac{1-2a}2$. From these:$$-\frac13=\frac12-a$$

Answer (score 1):

After getting $x=\frac   {1-2a}2$ from the second equation you get $3[(\frac   {1-2a}2-2)(\frac   {1-2a}2+\frac a 3)]=2\frac   {1-2a}2$ from the first equation. Solve this for $a$.

Comment: Whatever I get for $a$ , will that be the answer? can you say why?

Comment: That is what you get from the two equations. So the value of $a$ you get from the equation I wrote is the final answer. @SouradipDas

Comment: Oh ok thanks got it